# LinkedIn native applications break Google OAuth (bug report/feature request)

Tags: webview, google-oauth, linkedin-api

When a user attempts to go to a site within LinkedIn's mobile apps, any attempts to log into that site via Google's OAuth 2.0 v2 or above fails. This is due to upgrades in Google's security measures, [announced 2-1/2 years ago](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html) and released in October 2021.

I was expecting that, sometime within the past *30 months,* LinkedIn could update their product to replace WebViews with [Android Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs) and [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller). As it is, less and less of the web is able to log in from LinkedIn.

I was directed to Stack Overflow by LinkedIn's customer service, saying that this is where we would talk with LinkedIn engineers. The only messages I see here are from other developers saying "Sorry, deal with it." Is there any feedback available from LinkedIn directly?

Is this on any roadmap to be addressed?